# TFS Build issue/error in visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, tfsbuild

## TFS Build issue/error in visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core

#### Summary Build 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)###

**Exit code 100 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc shelve /saved /replace /recursive /comment:@d:\a_temp\tmp79.tmp _Build_5127 d:\a\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.**

Comment: Could you share related build definition? According to your error info please double check your mapping settings.

Comment: Thank You @Patrick-MSFT i have Solved ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 100 means that nothing succeeded.

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194959%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Can you try the same command from a command prompt?

Comment: Yes and Thank you @Bernard